# Find all references of a symbol in VS Code (Golang) return 0 result

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Wondering if anyone got `find all references` working for VS Code with Golang.

Using VS Code version: `1.23.1`.

Seems like it has all the necessary extensions needed like (go-langserver, guru). Still, `find all references` returns no results.

Comment: `grep -rni` is your friend (:

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a project with modules (outside GOPATH).

`guru` does not support modules.

(See: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24661)

After I installed `gopls` and enabled it in VS Code via the setting `go.useLanguageServer` `find all references` did worked again.

(The VS Code Go extension doesn't use `gopls` by default.)

See: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go#language-server

Comment: This has worked for me. To clarify the step of installing gopls, press Ctrl + Shft + P (Windows) to bring command pallet. Then type "Go: Install/Update Tools", check gopls@latest and click OK. Once installed, the Find All References started working.